# How to get local notification display on active state exactly as it shows up in inactive sate

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I am currently doing this, but the notification repeats several times.Please help.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];



    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
      UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        //localNotification.userInfo = @"Hey";
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        localNotification.alertBody = self.notiname;
        localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1104);
 }
}
```

Comment: define active and inactive state

Comment: What do you think that code does, exactly?  You're creating a loop by delivering a new notification every time one arrives.

Comment: Thanks for the edit shubhank, 
Avi - ya it's creating a loop.. how to do it in inactive state then?

Comment: You have to create your own notification view. Check out this library that seems to be what you are looking for https://github.com/nhdang103/HDNotificationView

Comment: Why would you create a new local notification when you receive one?  I think this code is just in the wrong place entirely, never mind the app's state at the time.